# What to do with apps running on iOS 5 and below for identifierForVender

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, udid

I have heard over the last couple of days that Apple are making it so that apps that use the UDID identifier of the device that they are running on will be rejected from the Apple App store ([Here is where I have read this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1560202)). They advise developers to use the `identifierForVender` which was introduced in iOS 6. I don't have an issue with this easy to change over, but what do I use if I still want to support devices running on an `iOS` below `iOS6`? Can I still use the UDID identifier or not? I don't believe this is very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app will be rejected if you continue to use `uniqueIdentifier` independently of the iOS version. I recommend using [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) instead, which is a drop-in replacement for the deprecated `uniqueIdentifier`.

You could check whether `identifierForVendor` is available, or you can use OpenUDID in all cases.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)]) {
    // Use: [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
} else {
    // Use: [OpenUDID value];
}
```

Comment: I do like this as an answer but I would have thought since Apple have said this they would have a solution for those that are using it. Is there anything from Apple themselves about how to do this?

Comment: Apple did deprecate this method due to privacy concerns. They only want to make sure that uniqueIdentifier won't be used in any applications from now on. There are no official recommendations. You can either force your users to use iOS 6.0+ or find an alternative (like OpenUDID).

Comment: I thought they would do that. Thanks. I normally leave answers a day or two so everyone has a chance to give an answer. If no one gives a better answer I will accept yours +1.

Comment: By the way, I've been using OpenUDID for a while without any problems so far. Looks like an optimal solution until we can forget about supporting iOS 5.x! :) Good luck!

Comment: Hi All, i have implemented OpenUDID in one of my applications,Will this be approved by apple? Bcz i have been going through some of the post where they mentioned that usage of Uipasteboard might be an issue in the future for storing this Identifier generated using CFUUID.

Comment: It will be approved. At least, it won't be rejected because of this.