# where should I put the code for reading device unique ID in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, performance

I have the following code for reading the unique device id. Since this will be used in more than 20 different views (.m files), I'm just questioning myself that is there a cleaning and efficient way of doing this? So I just comes up with 3 options:

Option One: Just do a copy/paste of these codes into any place I need them to be executed. I think this would be the worst way of doing this.

Option Two: Put it into AppDelegate.m. This will just run these once per launch (may save a tiny amount of time if I'm right). Then just call the string "stringDeviceID" whenever I need.

Option Three: Create another class and get these codes into a class function. However, this still have the "problem" of executing the code every time.

And my question is which is the best/better option I have to go with? And if there is another option that would even better than any of these, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
NSString *stringDeviceID;

if ([UIDevice instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)])
{
    stringDeviceID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
}
else
{
    stringDeviceID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: What about a category on `UIDevice`?

Comment: Your app will get reject from the Apple App store from the 1st May if you use `uniqueIdentifier` please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614903/what-to-do-with-apps-running-on-ios-5-and-below-for-identifierforvender

Comment: You can create a static function and export the file where you put this function in the pch or just use a macro

Comment: @Popeye: The whole point of this code is to use `identifierForVendor` if it exists, but fall back if it doesn't. And the ability to strip it out in a single place when it's time to drop iOS 5 support/when Apple forces you to is exactly why you'd want to wrap it up instead of copying and pasting it 20 times…

Comment: @abarnert That'll probably be enough to get you rejected from the store as there will still be linkage to a deprecated API - even if it's never called.

Comment: @Marko: You still may want to get your 1.0 version in before May 1st, or you may want to send the message dynamically instead of directly (which may or may not get around the AS rejection), or you may want to change to OpenUDID in 1.1, or… But really, _anything_ you want to do (besides just refusing to support anything pre-6.0), you need this wrapper, so it's still a good question.

Comment: @abarnert I will stand corrected but from what I understand it can't be used at all. So you would have to switch to something like openUDID.

Comment: @abarnert that was a bit rude but I will accept that you may have not been brought up with manners like some of us. "the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs" This says to me that you can no long after do any app submissions update or new for any app that still uses it so way bother even adding it to your apps now and not just use something like openUDID. It seems pointless doing the work twice so why not save yourself some time and do it once.

Comment: @Popeye: I'm assuming that you _do_ understand that 25 March is before 1 May, and therefore that you have an unspoken assumption. If you want to take that as me assuming the opposite (implying that you're an idiot), well, I can't stop you from taking offense at imagined slights. At any rate, the assumption is the key thing. There are plenty of apps that go for months without updates. Every Apple deadline is met with developers rushing to get their current version in ASAP. This is a perfectly reasonable business decision sometimes, bad management others… but the effect is the same either way.

Comment: just store the value in a custom NSObject class, store the value as a static var, make a static property. Takes 5 seconds and you only read it once :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement it as a category on UIDevice:

```
@iumplementation UIDevice (backwardCompatibleIdentifier)
- (NSString *)backwardCompatibleIdentifier {
    // your code
}
@end
```

Then, all you have to do is:

```
NSString *myid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] backwardCompatibleIdentifier];
```

I seriously doubt the performance cost of calling this 20 times will make any real performance difference. If you're worried, test it. If it *is* a problem, you can stick a cache inside the implementation. If even calling `currentDevice` is too slow, you can make it a class method instead of an instance method.

Your other alternatives are mostly reasonable, except for one: do not copy and paste this 20 times. At some point, you're going to want to remove the `uniqueIdentifier` call (whether because Apple forces you, or just because you want to drop iOS 5 compatibility). You may want to add OpenUDID or some other third-party library. Whatever you do, you want to be able to change it in 1 place, not change it in 19 places and then 6 months later debug the 1 place you forgot…

Comment: its much easier to just make a NSObject and create a static(+) method to retrieve it, since it would not need to be thread safe. I was not the one who downvoted you, btw in case your wandering. or wondering, even